# Issues with downloads from large dataset in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-studio

I've been trying various APIs from quandl4j and alpha vantage to get a large data set containing various stock info; however, when trying all of these I noticed that some of them only allow me to grab the last three years of data only. When using my browser with the same link I can go back 20 years.

I can't figure out why Android Studio is doing this. I tried setting the timeout long enough but it still only grabs a portion of the data. This is true whether I am using an API like quandl4j or using async task with a URL I made locally - both only allow me up to a certain date "2014-03-27".

Comment: Can you show readers how you are calling the API in Android Studio? Is there an API GUI interface, and if so can it should the exact GET/POST params being made?